Override Java Exception
We have a large codebase in Java. At various times we experience an OutOfMemory. It is not easy to override the throwable everywhere with a custom myThrowable.
I would like to override the standard OutOfMemory throwable to send a server alert to admins with the server ID. Is it possible?  The server alerting is easy I just don't know the syntax to override. Checked StackOverflow and AI no solution.
PS. Yes I know once an OOM occurs it may fail to execute but I would like to try.

An OutOfMemoryError is not an Exception, it is an Error. It will cause the VM to shutdown since no more memory is available to perform any task. Errors are not supposed to be caught and handled by your own code. Errors are hardcoded in the VM and as far as I know can not be replaced by any custom subclass of Error and definitely not by myException. Your alerting will have to happen outside of the JVM by watching the java process and potentially checking the log file for that Error.

You should be far more concerned with profiling your code and finding out why you're running out of memory than handling that error.   "Large codebase" suggests "old".   How has the load changed over time?   What parts are consuming a lot of memory?   Can you increase the amount of memory allocated to the process?   Lots of better things to try first.

There is a jvm startup option -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError which runs a  supplied system command.  This appears to have its own caveats but here is one explanation of usage.

Flight Recorder and JDK Mission Control and Java Management Extensions

@Computable, that sounds like a correct and useful answer to the question, not just a comment.

Yes, I realize it is a Throwable and not an Exception - brainfart I apologize.
The fact is the logging is not showing when this happens so I am trying to alert as well and that is not working. Overriding throwable would catch every instance of the OOM and allow me to fix and alert.
Thank you.

This demonstrates how to use the -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError jvm option.
This option is detailed here along with other possible error condition handling.
The idea is the VM shall execute your provided "command"(s) on detection of the condition and prior to throwing the error and subsequently terminating the program.
OOM Generator
First the program to generate the OutOfMemory error (may be simpler ways but this works):
import java.util.*;

public class TestOnOutOfMemory {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Start TestOnOutOfMemory");
      List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
      while(true) {
         Integer a[] = new Integer[1_000_000_000];
         b.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
      }
   }
}

(To accelerate the desired effect a small heap size is used to effect the result quicker as in java -Xms4m -Xmx16m for example.  This is not required and result is same though exception error may occur in a different spot.)
Base Case
In this example I simply execute a 'curl --help' command but obviously you could replace with a useful curl request to a server endpoint.
$ java -Xms4m -Xmx16m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl --help" TestOnOutOfMemory
Start TestOnOutOfMemory
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl --help"
#   Executing "curl --help"...
Usage: curl [options...] <url>
 -d, --data <data>          HTTP POST data
 -f, --fail                 Fail fast with no output on HTTP errors
 -h, --help <category>      Get help for commands
 -i, --include              Include protocol response headers in the output
 -o, --output <file>        Write to file instead of stdout
 -O, --remote-name          Write output to a file named as the remote file
 -s, --silent               Silent mode
 -T, --upload-file <file>   Transfer local FILE to destination
 -u, --user <user:password> Server user and password
 -A, --user-agent <name>    Send User-Agent <name> to server
 -v, --verbose              Make the operation more talkative
 -V, --version              Show version number and quit

This is not the full help, this menu is stripped into categories.
Use "--help category" to get an overview of all categories.
For all options use the manual or "--help all".
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at TestOnOutOfMemory.main(TestOnOutOfMemory.java:12)

As you can see the provided "command" is executed prior to the VM declaring the error (at bottom).
Multiple Commands
Multiple commands can be provided separated by a semicolon:
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl --help; pwd"

demonstrated here:
$ java -Xms4m -Xmx16m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl --help; pwd" TestOnOutOfMemory
Start TestOnOutOfMemory
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl --help; pwd"
#   Executing "curl --help"...
Usage: curl [options...] <url>
 -d, --data <data>          HTTP POST data
 -f, --fail                 Fail fast with no output on HTTP errors
 -h, --help <category>      Get help for commands
 -i, --include              Include protocol response headers in the output
 -o, --output <file>        Write to file instead of stdout
 -O, --remote-name          Write output to a file named as the remote file
 -s, --silent               Silent mode
 -T, --upload-file <file>   Transfer local FILE to destination
 -u, --user <user:password> Server user and password
 -A, --user-agent <name>    Send User-Agent <name> to server
 -v, --verbose              Make the operation more talkative
 -V, --version              Show version number and quit

This is not the full help, this menu is stripped into categories.
Use "--help category" to get an overview of all categories.
For all options use the manual or "--help all".
#   Executing "pwd"...
/g/java/onOutOfMemory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at TestOnOutOfMemory.main(TestOnOutOfMemory.java:12)

Synchronous
It is evident that the commands are executed in a sequential, synchronous manner, although no docs were found stating this.
Here the curl command hits an endpoint to demonstrate the curl transaction is completed before the next command in list and before the VM generating the exception.
$ java -Xms4m -Xmx16m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl www.example.com; pwd" TestOnOutOfMemory
Start TestOnOutOfMemory
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl www.example.com; pwd"
#   Executing "curl www.example.com"...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1256  100  1256    0     0  26089      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 26723<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

#   Executing "pwd"...
/g/java/onOutOfMemory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at TestOnOutOfMemory.main(TestOnOutOfMemory.java:11)

Combine Options (Heap Dump + OOM event commands)
You can also combine options such that first a heap dump is performed (to a file) and then available for subsequent commands.  Here the heap dump is performed and an ls command shows it exists.  (I have not seen any docs which guarantees order of option processing (i.e. the heap dump before commands) which this example requires to be effective.)
$ java -Xms4m -Xmx16m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl www.example.com; pwd; ls java_*" TestOnOutOfMemory
Start TestOnOutOfMemory
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid33104.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [2673949 bytes in 0.006 secs]
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="curl www.example.com; pwd; ls java_*"
#   Executing "curl www.example.com"...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1256  100  1256    0     0  25686      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 26723<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

#   Executing "pwd"...
/g/java/onOutOfMemory
#   Executing "ls java_*"...
java_pid33104.hprof
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at TestOnOutOfMemory.main(TestOnOutOfMemory.java:11)

Another VM
Finally, if you are intent on using Java to perform your "command" processing you can just start a new VM with your error reporting implementation as in -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="java MyErrorLogger" .

This was very detailed and informative. It does not answer my question but instead gives me an alternate solution. I may end up going this route. I can call a curl to another VM which in turn sends the alert.
I am needing to log the throwable-error and alert on it to restart the VM. I am getting no log captured when this happens and I can't work out where in the codebase to focus.
Thank you for this option.

If it isn't at all possible to figure the cause of the OutOfMemoryError Exception (assuming you have tried), One way to gracefully Shutdown will be to add Shutdown Hooks.
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { database.close(); }
});

Use the code block above to write your own workflow of how you want to log or notify admins.

This is also executed at regular shutdowns, you have no way of finding out about the OutOfMemoryError other than reading a log file where the error hopefully already ended up.
